# Trying To Make Cleaner C# in Razor File With ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I've got the code below where I am checking for a default value in an options list.  It works, but it's ugly if/else logic.  The quotes have me stumped in how to optimize to be cleaner C# code.  Looking for a way to make it nicer, perhaps even just one clean line of code.

```
@foreach (var myValue in ratingControlValues)
{
    if (myValue.Equals(ratingControlInitialValue))
    {
        <option value="@myValue" selected='selected'>@myValue</option>
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="@myValue" >@myValue</option>
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a boolean value your testing ?, thought about enums ?

Comment: well then look into [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or html helpers

Comment: You don't show code for creating options list, but there's an overload for [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor) that includes selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`The Select Tag Helper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper)

In your controller you can assign the options to a property of your view model or view bag

```
var ratings = ratingControlValues
    .Select(myValue => new SelectListItem { 
        Value = myValue, 
        Text = myValue,
        Selected = myValue.Equals(ratingControlInitialValue)
    }).ToList();

ViewBag.RatingsOptions = ratings;
```

The above example sets the values using the `ViewBag`

This will now allow the view to be simplified using the tag-helper

```
<select asp-for="Ratings" asp-items="ViewBag.RatingsOptions"></select>
```

to a simple single line of markup